# kafka bootstrap server stale list of broker ips

Tags: apache-kafka

I have written a kafka consumer. During initialisation, i give a list of bootstrap server ips in the form of ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip3:9092. Over a period of time, the ip2 and ip3 may be replaced with another ip4 and ip5. But we may fail to update the bootstrap server list given to client. Ideally kafka consumer would work as long as there is atleast one working node ip.

In my application i am making a call to fetchallpartition (this issue is not specific to this call though) for a topic. To fetch all partition list, kafka consumer first figures out least loaded node, since ip2 and ip3 don't have any connection they would come on the top randomly (as during startup every node is least loaded), and when kafka consumer make a call to ip2 or ip3, it keeps on retrying and eventually default.api.timeout.ms limit hits and we get apitimeout exception.

below is the error i get in my logs

```
Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

I have some question wrt it

1. Is it possible to set connection timeout to a node? so that we don't keep on retrying.
2. Is it possible to set limit of retries of connection to a node?

Comment: Rather than IP addresses, you could use DNS names, then set a short DNS cache time in your app / router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [this](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/8683) pr
`socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms`
Can be used to set lower timeout of connection establishment.

This change is available since [kafka client version 2.7.](https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation.html#consumerconfigs)

[This](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-601%3A+Configurable+socket+connection+timeout+in+NetworkClient) wiki has more details for implementation.